# fetching from list and then putting data in method parameters

Tags: java, list

I have the below method which take six parameters in which the last two parameters p5 and p6 i take from array list that is..

```
public void generateR(String p1,
            String p2, String p3, String p4,
            String p5, String p6) {

    }
```

the below list contain those parameters (p5 , p5) in an list..

It`erator<CaObject> iterator = iaList.iterator();`

now i need to call  my above method keeping one thing in mind that in during each list iteration the value of parameter p5 and p6 is taken from list

that is something like this

/`/ Iterator<CaObject> iterator = ioList.iterator();`

//then call this method , but in p5 and p6 the value of first index of list will go first and then of second index until the list end up

```
  public void generateR(String p1,
            String p2, String p3, String p4,
            String p5, String p6) {

    }
```

at he backed entering the value of P5 and p6 in list in this fashion..

```
List<Pair> pairList = new ArrayList<Pair>();
        Map<Long, Integer> result = new LinkedHashMap<Long, Integer>();
        for (Object[] arr : list) {
            result.put((Long) arr[0], (Integer) arr[1]);

        }
```

please advise how to achieve this

Comment: just to clarify, p5 gets the odd elements of the list, and p6 the even ones? p1 to p4 are fixed and not related?

Answer (score 0):

Try to rewrite this method using varargs `generateR(String... p)` or String array `generateR(String[] p)`

Comment: can you please explain in detail, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Pretty Bad the way in which Method is designed.

Yes, Either use an array as a parameter to your method or As Alexander suggested use a VarArg to method.

```
generateR(String[] stringArray)
```

You can initialize this array the way you want and as many parameters as you like.

Hope this helps!

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
private void listWalker(String p1, String p2, String p3, String p4, Collection<String> list)
{
   for(int i = 1; i < list.size(); i+=2)
   {
      generateR(p1, p2, p3, p4, list.get(i-1), list.get(i));
   }
}
```

The function takes the 4 fixed parameters and iterates the list, starting from the second element of the list. In each iteration the index counter is increased by 2. If the list has an odd number of elements, the last will be ignored.
In the for loop body, the method is called using the 4 method parameters and two elements of the list, i.e. the previous and the current one.